# <option> values showing as 0 in database

Tags: php

I cannot upload to the database drop down menu variables, when the form is submitted the text area is blank. I am new to coding and all of the information I have found thus far has been unable to help me. The students first and last names are submitting fine I just now need to process their grades

These are the Subjects:

```
English<br>  
<select name="Grade">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="A*">A*</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
   </select><br>
Maths<br> 
<select name="Grade2">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="A*">A*</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
   </select><br>
Science<br>   
<select name="Grade3">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="A*">A*</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
   </select><br>
```

I need to upload them to here:

```
$DB_HOST = "localhost";
$DB_USERNAME = "admin";
$DB_PASSWORD = "chichester";
$DB_NAME = "results";

$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$examboard = $_POST["examboard"];
$grade = $_POST["grade"];
$grade2 = $_POST["grade2"];
$grade3 = $_POST["grade3"];
$additionalcomments = $_POST["Additional Comments"];

$conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO studentresults (Name,lastname,examboard,additionalcomments) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$examboard','$grade','$grade2','$grade3','$additionalcomments')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO studentresults (grade, grade2, grade3) VALUES ('$grade','$grade2','$grade3')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "Student exam results have been successfully submitted. "; 
} else {
    echo "Error, please try again later. : " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

//close connection
$conn->close();
```

Now how do I overcome this, the script and database does not show an errors. All I need to do is process a series of exam results and display this in a database. The  tag seems to have confused matters.

Comment: enable PHP errors to be displayed since they are likely getting written to a log file currently.  You can enable display by adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script

Comment: Grade !== grade

Answer (score 0):

1) you are updating the insert query.

2) The query you have written is wrong as there number of columns is different than the number of values given.

3)  `$_POST["Additional Comments"];` this won't work, as array key cannot contain space.

Comment: So having made these changes will I see the information in the database?

Comment: try fixing these first, let's see what else comes up

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: grade in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Assignment/MySQL.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: grade2 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Assignment/MySQL.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: grade3 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Assignment/MySQL.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: additionalcomments in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Assignment/MySQL.php on line 18

Comment: they have to be `G` instead of `g`

Comment: Thank you, why is this necessary?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: additionalcomments in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Assignment/MySQL.php on line 21

Comment: where is that declared in html?

Comment: Change additionalcomments also in the form. Names must match

Comment: There's no reason an array index can't have spaces.

Comment: <br> Additional Comments <br>
 <textarea name ="additionalcomments" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea><br/>

Comment: Yes, wish I could buy you a drink!

Comment: @ZakComber   
haha thanks, mark it as answered if that solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two $sql insert statements? Only use one.

```
INSERT INTO ___ (col1,col2) VALUES ('data1','data2');
```

You can't have spaces  in $_POST['']; variables.

Comment: No reason an array index can't have spaces.